# What is the best place to store the application.properties file for a Spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an `application.properties` file which I have placed at the same level as the `src` folder. Things are working correctly. But, is this the standard place to keep this file? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 3):

I place them at `src/main/resources`. Some would prefer `src/main/resources/config`. When deploying, I put the customized properties at the same folder where the jar is placed. Again, some would prefer the `config` sub folder.

[Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) picks the files from these locations by default.

Answer (score 0):

Under *src* folder create another folder named config let's say. Here create another folder named *local*. Than place your file here. This structure is used when you want to deploy to different servers(i.e. *local, test, live*).

Then you can create profiles and for example you can configure Maven to choose the proper application.properties file located in one of these folders to create the war and deploy.

So have something live config/local/application.properties and at least config/live/application.properties

**UPDATE**

What IDE are you using? You need to declare the path as a resource path. See how to do that depending on what you are developing. At build time, the path need to contain some resources, i.e. one or more folders in which the .properties files will be placed.

You can also try the path sugested in another answers src/main/resources (it is more explicit I agree) but the thing is that you can place your resources anywhere but you need to declare the location as a resource location.

Comment: I created `src/config/local/application.properties`. But it was not detected. However, if I create `config/` at the same level as `src`, then `application.properties` is detected.